# Decrease the computation time for DGELSD subroutine

Tags: matlab, fortran, intel-mkl

I am writing a code in Fortran that involve computation of linear least squares (A^(-1)*b). For this I have used the subroutine "DGELSD". I am able to get the correct answer from my code. I have cross checked my solution with that of the data available from MATLAB.

Now when it comes to the computation time, MATLAB is taking much less time than that of my .f90 code. The main motivation for me to write the .f90 code was to do heavy computations, as MATLAB was unable to handle this problem (as the matrix size is increased, it takes more and more time). I am talking of the order of matrix around (10^6 x 10^6).

I know that I may be lacking somewhere around the vectorization or parallelization of code (as I am new to it). But would it make any difference? As the subroutine "DGELSD" is already highly optimized. Also I am using Intel ifort compiler and visual studio as an editor.

I have attached the part of the main code (.f90) below for reference. Please suggest what can be done to decrease the computation time. I am having good hardware configuration to run heavy computation.

Workstation specification: Intel Xeon 32 core - 64 bit processor, 64 GB RAM.

Code information:

a) I have used 'DGELSD' example available on Intel MKL example site..

b) I am using x64 architecture.

c) This is the code I am using in MATLAB for comparison.

```
function min_norm_check(m,n)
tic
a=15*m*n;
b=15*m*n;
c=6;
A=rand(a,b);
B=rand(b,c);
C=A\B;
toc
end
```

This is the Fotran code given below:

```
! Program to check the time required to
! calculate linear least square solution 
! using DGELSD subroutine

PROGRAM MAIN

      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER :: M,N,LDA,LDB,NRHS,NB,NG

      REAL :: T1,T2,START,FINISH

      DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: D_CAP,A,B,TG,DG

      INTEGER :: I=0

      NB=10
      NG=10

      M = 15*NB*NG
      N = 15*NB*NG
      NRHS = 6
!!

      LDA   = MAX(M,N)
      LDB   = MAX(M,NRHS)
!
      ALLOCATE (A(LDA,N))
      ALLOCATE (B(LDB,NRHS))

      A = 0
      B = 0

      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(A)

      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(B)

      CALL CPU_TIME(START)

      DO I=1,1

          WRITE(*,*) I

          CALL CALC_MIN_NORM_D(M,N,LDA,LDB,NRHS,A,B,D_CAP)   

      ENDDO

      CALL CPU_TIME(FINISH)

      WRITE(*,*)'("TIME =',FINISH-START,'SECONDS.")'

      END

      SUBROUTINE CALC_MIN_NORM_D(M,N,LDA,LDB,NRHS,A,B,D_CAP)
!
!     SUBROUTINE DEFINITION TO CALCULATE THE 
!     LINEAR LEAST SQUARE SOLUTION OF ([A]^-1*B)
!
      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER :: M,N,NRHS,LDA,LDB,LWMAX,INFO,LWORK,RANK

      DOUBLE PRECISION RCOND

      INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: IWORK

      DOUBLE PRECISION :: A(LDA,N),B(LDB,NRHS),D_CAP(LDB,NRHS) 
      DOUBLE PRECISION, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: S,WORK
!
      WRITE(*,*)'IN CALC MIN NORM BEGINING'
      WRITE(*,*)'DGELSD EXAMPLE PROGRAM RESULTS'

      LWMAX = 1E8

      ALLOCATE(S(M))
      ALLOCATE(IWORK(3*M*0+11*M))
      ALLOCATE(WORK(LWMAX))

!     NEGATIVE RCOND MEANS USING DEFAULT (MACHINE PRECISION) VALUE
      RCOND = -1.0
!
!     QUERY THE OPTIMAL WORKSPACE.
!
      LWORK = -1
      CALL DGELSD( M, N, NRHS, A, LDA, B, LDB, S, RCOND, RANK, WORK,LWORK, IWORK, INFO )

      LWORK = MIN( LWMAX, INT( WORK( 1 ) ) )

      !WRITE(*,*) 'AFTER FIRST DGELSD'
!
!     SOLVE THE EQUATIONS A*X = B.
!!!
      CALL DGELSD( M, N, NRHS, A, LDA, B, LDB, S, RCOND, RANK, WORK,LWORK, IWORK, INFO )

!
!     CHECK FOR CONVERGENCE.
!

      IF( INFO.GT.0 ) THEN
      WRITE(*,*)'THE ALGORITHM COMPUTING SVD FAILED TO CONVERGE;'
      WRITE(*,*)'THE LEAST SQUARES SOLUTION COULD NOT BE COMPUTED.'
      STOP
      END IF
!
!
      WRITE(*,*)' EFFECTIVE RANK = ', RANK

      !D_CAP = B

      END
```

This is the build log for successful compilation of the file. As I am using Visual studio with intel visual fortran, I can compile my program using Compile option available in the editor. I mean to say I don't have to use command line interface to run my program.

```
Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler 17.0.2.187 [IA-32]...
ifort /nologo /debug:full /Od /warn:interfaces /module:&quotDebug\\&quot /object:&quotDebug\\&quot /Fd&quotDebug\vc110.pdb&quot /traceback /check:bounds /check:stack /libs:dll /threads /dbglibs /c /Qlocation,link,&quotC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\\bin&quot /Qm32 &quotD:\Google Drive\Friday_May_27_2016\Mtech Thesis Job\All new work\Fortran coding\fortran hfgmc\Console6\Console6\Console6.f90&quot
Linking...
Link /OUT:&quotDebug\Console6.exe&quot /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:&quotDebug\Console6.exe.intermediate.manifest&quot /MANIFESTUAC:&quotlevel='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'&quot /DEBUG /PDB:&quotD:\Google Drive\Friday_May_27_2016\Mtech Thesis Job\All new work\Fortran coding\Console6\Console6\Debug\Console6.pdb&quot /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /IMPLIB:&quotD:\Google Drive\Friday_May_27_2016\Mtech Thesis Job\All new work\Fortran coding\fortran hfgmc\Console6\Console6\Debug\Console6.lib&quot -qm32 &quotDebug\Console6.obj&quot
Embedding manifest...
mt.exe /nologo /outputresource:&quotD:\Google Drive\Friday_May_27_2016\Mtech Thesis Job\All new work\Fortran coding\fortran hfgmc\Console6\Console6\Debug\Console6.exe;#1&quot /manifest &quotDebug\Console6.exe.intermediate.manifest&quot

Console6 - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Also I have included the intel mkl library, shown in the figure below:
[image]

---

I have compiled the program and the output has been written in file 'OUTPUT_FILE.TXT'.

```
IN CALC MIN NORM BEGINING

DGELSD EXAMPLE PROGRAM RESULTS

EFFECTIVE RANK =         1500

IN CALC MIN NORM ENDING

("TIME TAKEN TO SOLVE DGELSD=   4.290028     SECONDS.")
```

On the other hand MATLAB gives the following result in the output command window:

```
min_norm_check(10,10)
```

Elapsed time is 0.224172 seconds.

---

Also I don't want to outperform MATLAB, its easy and simple. But with increase in the size of the problem, MATLAB stops responding. I have left my program to run on MATLAB for more than two days. It still haven't produced any results.

Comment: How are you compiling it? Are you sure you're linking to the Intel's MKL library and not some other lapack on the system?

Comment: yes I have inculded intel math kernel library only..... , It can be directly added in visual stdio through the property module of console.

Comment: Show us your compilation and linking commands.

Comment: Please enter the compilation log again as pure text. I cleaned it somewhat, but some characters are wrong now. But more important is to show us your time measurements so that we can see how long does it take. Both versions, Matlab and Fortran.

Comment: Matlab is probably linked with a parallel BLAS/Lapack. If in yur compiler flags you asked for a sequential MKL, your code will be take more time, especially on a 32 core machine.

Comment: If 99% of your time is spent in LAPACK with matlab, Fortran will not make your code faster than matlab.

Comment: In the Fortran case, does your calculation take 4 seconds in real (wall) time (from your experience)? If the calculation is threaded, cpu_time() may show total CPU time much longer than real (wall, elapsed) time. Also, it is probably better to use "Release" rather than "Debug" compile mode... (Still, it seems almost impossible to deal with 10^6 x 10^6 systems with dense matrices...)

Comment: Hello roygvib,  Yes the time information is correct and it matches with real time also. Also the matrix I am talking about is a kind of stiffness matrix and it is mostly a sparse matrix. It is mostly populated with diagonal elements. Thanks

Comment: On my Mac mini (core-i7, 4-core, gfortran-6), your Fortran code runs in 1.6 sec (in real, elapsed time) and 4.0 sec (in total CPU time reported by cpu_time()), and optimization levels do not matter (-O0 and -Ofast give the same result) because all the computation is spent in LAPACK (which seems to be threaded, from Apple's library). So it may be interesting to try [system_clock()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465101/fortran-parallel-programming), together with the "Release" mode.

Comment: Another point is to check whether MKL runs in parallel by monitoring the CPU/thread usage, or by explicitly specifying MKL_NUM_THREADS (but I don't know how to do it on Windows...sorry). Matlab is also very likely using many threads. Another possibility is that Matlab is using a different algorithm as a linear solver for almost diagonal matrices internally (e.g., [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084987/how-does-matlab-solve-large-symmetric-and-sparse-linear-systems)). If the algorithms used are different between Matlab and Fortran, the timing becomes naturally different.

Comment: hello all>>>>>>> ................ can i use openMP to make my code run faster...... i dont know anything about openMP, and i doubt that would it make any difference to lapack subroutine computations......... please provide me a link or suggestion if it is possible to run the code faster with openmp application, that include lapack subroutines, faster. THANKS